# Reordering in IconView (PyGtk)

Tags: python, pygtk

Using PyGtk's IconView, I can set the icons to be reorderable by calling `gtk.IconView.set_reorderable(True)`.  My question is what is the best way to retrieve the new order?  That is, how should I access a property of each of the elements in the new order?  An iterator of sorts?

I am using gtk.ListStore to store the data.

I know this might sound trivial but I have virtually no experience in Python or PyGtk (or GTK in general) so I'd like to know the right way!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I understand now: it turns out that when items are reordered in `IconView`, `gtk.ListStore.reorder` or something similar is called.  What that means is that all I needed to do was to use `gtk.ListStore.get_iter()` or `gtk.ListStore.get_iter_first()` and all the problems are solved.

How trivial!  All I needed to do was eat over it it seems.